# Is it possible to display the statistics from the Google Developer Console on a web site?

Tags: android, google-api

I am wondering whether it is possible to use the Google API to display some data from the Developer Console statistics on a web site. Has anyone done something like that already?

I really would like to display the installs of my apps on my web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API for retrieving this data, sorry.

Besides that, the Google Play statistics are notoriously inaccurate and displaying them will likely end up being misleading.