# Display the Google Maps Javascript API usage statistics on a custom website

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm currently using the Google Maps Javascript API for displaying multiple Google Maps on a website. Since the usage is limited for non-paying users, I am trying to keep the usage as low as possible, but I would love to have a way to monitor those usage stats in a semi-realtime way.

I know that you can lookup these usage statistics in the Google Development Center, for different timespans, but I was wondering if it's possible to query those usage statistics in some sort of way for displaying them on a custom webpage?

I've already tried to find some topics here on StackOverflow around this subject, but the only one I've found that comes near to my question is this one from 2013:

[Is it possible to display the statistics from the Google Developer Console on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927785/is-it-possible-to-display-the-statistics-from-the-google-developer-console-on-a)

In that topic the correct answer was that it wasn't possible at that moment.

Is this still not possible at this moment or does anybody know a way to get those usage statistics out of the Development Center?

Comment: Would google analytics real time reporting api be an option? Shouldn't that give you the amount of request? It is still in beat but maybe this is worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not see the statics on a custom web page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the usage information out of the Developers Console, but you could wire up the Maps JavaScript API to report back to your own analytics services which is easier to embed.

As an example, using Google Analytics, every time your code runs `new google.maps.Map(..` you could run `ga('send', 'event', 'map', load');` reporting that a map was loaded.  The numbers might vary slightly since some users block analytics but I would expect them to line up closely.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out a different way to retrieve similar statistics!